# Proof for the cancellation law of addition for natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, induction

I'm trying to prove this by induction but I'm afraid I didn't quite make good use of the induction hypothesis. Here's my attempt where I assume $0\in \mathbb{N}$ (that's what I mean by $\mathbb{N_{0}}$):

*Proof*. We are trying to show that $\forall m,n,p\in \mathbb{N_{0}}:m+p=n+p\implies m=n$.

**Base case**: Fix $m,n\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$. If $p=0$ and $m+p=n+p$. Then,
\begin{align*}m&:=m+0=m+p=n+p=n+0:=n\end{align*}

So, $p=0\implies (m+p=n+p\implies m=n)$.

**Induction step**: Suppose $m+q=n+q\implies m=n$ for an arbitrary but fixed $q\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$. We may further assume\begin{align*}m+(q+1)=n+(q+1)\tag{$1$}\end{align*}

From $(1)$ we know that $(m+q)+1=(n+q)+1$. Now, our induction hypothesis **abstractly tells us** (my interpretation): $a+b=c+b\implies a=c$. Since $1=1$ and $a+1=c+1$ where $a=m+q$ and $c=n+q$ then $a=c$,that is $m+q=n+q$ but, again, from the induction hypothesis we can conclude now $m=n$ what finishes our induction on $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the $p=1$ case of the claim, which you can't at that point. Instead, the needed $$x+1=y+1\implies x=y$$ is immediately one of the Peano axioms (perhaps written in terms of the successor function intead of "$+1$")

Comment: May you explain me why I can't? I am not acquainted with the peano axioms, so could I use strong induction" from whose hypohtesis we know that the $p=1$ case would be true and finish this proof?

Comment: May I proof the $p=1$ case in order to use it in the proof as follows: By way of contradiction suppose $\exists m,n\in \mathbb{N_{0}}: m+1=n+1 \wedge n\ne m$. Since they exist we can choose $m=n=0$ which leads to an absurdity like $0\ne 0$?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation in the inductive step of your proof is a little weird ('abstractly tells us'?) ...

Also, while the cancellation theorem indeed says that if $a + c = b + c$, then $a = b$, you are in the middle of proving exactly that. So, there is a real danger of circular reasoning here.

But why even bring up $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Like you say, you can go from

$m+(q+1)=n+(q+1)$

to

$(m+q)+1=(n+q)+1$

to

$m+q=n+q$

to

$m = n$

Of course, for the first step you need to assume Association (can you assume that? Have you proven that? It can be proven from the Peano axioms using induction) and for the second step you need to already have shown that $m+1 = n + 1 \implies m +n$ ... or simply regard that as an 'obvious' mathematical truth (as Hagen points out, this is actually an elementary Peano axiom)

Comment: May I ask you something? If I am to prove something by induction and the statement I am trying to prove has more than 1 variable. May I treat the other variable (the one I am not doing the induction on) still as a variable whereas the one I'll do the  induction on variable would be more like a constant (otherwise I'll be assuming what is trying to be shown)?

Comment: @HannyBoy Yes. The $m$ and $n$ in the inductive hypothesis can be *any* number, so that includes the numbers $m + q$ and $n + q$, as they are numbers themselves

Comment: Oooooooooh, thank you. I've been wasted away by this doubt. Thnk youuuu!

Comment: Ah!  So now I understand why you did that weird thing with the $a, b, c$. :P. Yeah, there is really no reason for that at all.