# Is this proof of the cancellation law for natural numbers alright?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, induction, peano-axioms

**For starters:**

- $\mathbb{N_{0}}$ means $0\in \mathbb{N}$
- We define the addition between natural numbers (the suggested reading for my class does) as follows: Let $m$ and $n$ be natural numbers.

\begin{align*}n+0=0+n=n\tag{$a$}\\
n+(m+1)=(n+m)+1\tag{$b$}
\end{align*}

Our goal is to show: $\forall m,n,p\in \mathbb{N_{0}}: m+p=n+p\implies m=n$.

*Proof.* Let $m\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$.

**Base case:** If $p=0$ and $m+p=n+p$,
\begin{align*}
m+p&=n+p\\
m&=n\end{align*}

**Induction step:** Assume that for a fixed $q\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$\begin{align*}m+q=n+q\implies m=n\tag{$i$}\end{align*}Furthermore, let's suppose\begin{align*}m+(q+1)=n+(q+1)\tag{$ii$}\end{align*} Observe that according to $(i)$: \begin{align*}m\ne m\implies m+q\ne n+q.\tag{$iii$}\end{align*}

From $(b)$ we establised that $(ii)$ is equivalent to $(m+q)+1=(n+q)+1$.

Now, by way of contradiction we hypothesize the antecedent of $(iii)$. But such foregoing assumption would imply that, in particular, for the $q=1$ case it's true that $m+q\ne n+q$ no matter what $m$ and $n$ are because $q$ is fixed/constant after all but arbitrary.

So, by this contradiction against $(ii)$ we've shown ${m+(q+1)=n+(q+1)\implies m=n}$.

Comment: Already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4192058/proof-for-the-cancellation-law-of-addition-for-natural-numbers)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is it wrong though? In the linked question my proof was wrong and I would like to know whether it is again. Truth is I only got to know the axiom of the succesor because of this forum. Since I didn't appeared in my class textbook that's why I am trying to use contradiction.

Comment: How are you defining $+$ in terms of $+$?

Comment: The mistake in this question is the same of the previous one: mixing sum with successor and using $(m+1=n+1) \to (m+n)$ in the induction step, when you can use only the base case with $0$. Thus my answer is the same as the answer to your previous post: "separate" sum from successor and use the axiom for successor.

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

IMO it does not work: if we use in the proof $m≠n → (m+q≠n+q)$, this is exactly what we have to prove.

The "trick" is that in (a) and (b) above you are using $+$ in the def of $+$ and this is incorrect. In the definition of the binary operation $+$ we have to use the unary function $s$ (successor).

We assume (ii) and we get (iii) $s(m+q)=s(n+q)$ using the defintion of $+$.

By [Axiom for successor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic): $\forall x \forall y\ (s(x)=s(y) \to x=y)$, we get $m+q=n+q$ and now we can use the induction hypotheses concluding with $m=n$.